# what is the alternate for open sans in photoshop

Tags: fonts

i want to use open sans in adobe Photoshop, but cannot use it as it is not available. can you please tell me substitute for open sans

Answer (score 2):

[Open Sans](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans) is a free font. Surely the simplest idea is to download and install it, then restart Photoshop?